# Error on Using Comparator for Sort ArrayList inside doInBackground Method

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

i am working on an Android Apps that need to show sorted data by double value. The data is fetched from online database server. So far is going well until i want to sort the data, i read some thread and using Comparator method to sort my arraylist. But, it didn't work. I don't know what happen but there's no error log on my log cat and the data doesn't appear on the screen.

Please help me what i need to do sir?
Thanks.

NB. this the code for my doInBackground method where i doing the process of fetching and sorting the data.

```
    public class getCarRent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        URL hp = null;
        try {

            hp = new URL(getString(R.string.liveurl)
                    + "getCarRent.php?value=" + catId);
            // hp = new URL(
            // "http://192.168.1.106/restourant/foodtype.php?value="
            // + id);
            //Log.d("URL", "" + hp);
            URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
            hpCon.connect();
            InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();
            Log.d("input", "" + input);

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    input));

            String x = "";
            x = r.readLine();
            String total = "";

            while (x != null) {
                total += x;
                x = r.readLine();
            }
         //   Log.d("URL", "" + total);

            JSONArray j = new JSONArray(total);
         //   Log.d("URL1", "" + j.length());
            Item[] itemList = new Item[j.length()];
            resultList = new ArrayList<Item>();
            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                Item item = new Item();// buat variabel category
                //JSONObject Obj;
                JSONObject Obj = j.getJSONObject(i); //sama sperti yang lama, cman ini lebih mempersingkat karena getJSONObject cm d tulis sekali aja disini

                item.setId(Obj.getString(JF_ID));
                //item.setTitle(Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));


                item.setAddress(Obj.getString(JF_ADDRESS));

                item.setTelephoneNumber(Obj.optString(JF_TELEPHONE, NO_DATA_FOUND));

                item.setEmailAddress(Obj.optString(JF_EMAIL, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setWebUrl(Obj.optString(JF_WEB, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setFacebookUrl(Obj.optString(JF_FACEBOOK, NO_DATA_FOUND));

                item.setLatitude(Obj.optDouble(JF_LATITUDE, NULL_LOCATION));
                item.setLongitude(Obj.optDouble(JF_LONGITUDE, NULL_LOCATION));
                try {
                    item.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Obj.optString(JF_RATING, NO_DATA_FOUND)));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    item.setRating(0.0f);
                }

                try {
                    item.setRatingCount(Integer.parseInt(Obj.optString(JF_RATING_COUNT, NO_DATA_FOUND)));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    item.setRatingCount(0);
                }

                try {
                    item.setRatingCount(Integer.parseInt(Obj.optString(JF_RATINGSCORE, NO_DATA_FOUND)));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    item.setRatingCount(0);
                }


                item.setTagLine(Obj.optString(JF_TAG_LINE, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setDescription(Obj.optString(JF_DESCRIPTION, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setVerification(Obj.optString(JF_VERIFICATION, NO_DATA_FOUND).equals("1") ? true : false);

                item.setCarId(Obj.optString(JF_CARID, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setTitle(Obj.optString(JF_CARTITLE, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setCarRentalId(Obj.optString(JF_CARRENTALID, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setCarPrice(Obj.optString(JF_CARPRICE, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setCarYear(Obj.optString(JF_CARYEAR, NO_DATA_FOUND));

                JSONArray imgArr = Obj.getJSONArray("thumbImage");
                String[] imageThumb = new String[imgArr.length()];
                // String[] imageLarge = new String[imgArr.length()];

                for (int k = 0; k < imgArr.length(); k++) {
                    imageThumb[k] = imgArr.getString(k);
                    // imageLarge[k] = imgArr.getJSONObject(k).getString(JF_TITLE);
                }


                for(int l = 0; l <imgArr.length(); l++) {
                    item.setImageLargeUrls(imageThumb);
                }


                item.setImageThumbUrls(imageThumb);
                // item.setImageLargeUrls(imageLarge);

                //  JSONArray imgArr = Obj.getJSONArray("thumbImage");

                /*String[] imgCount = new String[imgArr.length()];
                for(int k = 0 ; k < imgCount.length; k++) {


                    imgCount[k] = imgArr.getString(k);
                    item.setImageThumbUrls(imgCount);
                }*/


                    Location trgtLocation = new Location("trgtLocation");
                    trgtLocation.setLatitude(item.getLatitude());
                    trgtLocation.setLongitude(item.getLongitude());

                    Log.d("LatLong", "Latitude "+String.valueOf(trgtLocation.getLatitude())+"Longitude "+ String.valueOf(trgtLocation.getLongitude()));

                    Location crntLocation = gTrack.getLocation(getActivity());


                    Log.d("crntLocation", String.valueOf(gTrack.getLocation(getActivity())));

                    item.setDistance(crntLocation.distanceTo(trgtLocation) / 1000);
                    Log.d("distance", String.valueOf(item.getDistance()));


                Log.d("URL1", "" + Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));

                resultList.add(item);

            }

           // itemList;//kayaknya bukan Item atau item

            Arrays.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
                    return lhs.getDistance().compareTo(rhs.getDistance());//mungkin valuenya null
                }
            });

            itemList.notify();

            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {

                Log.d("itemList", String.valueOf(itemList[i]));
            }



            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    resultListView.setAdapter(new ResultListAdapterRental(getActivity(), mCallbacks, resultList));
                }
            });

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is your fetching works fine?

Comment: yes, if i remove this code `Arrays.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
                    return lhs.getDistance().compareTo(rhs.getDistance());
                }
            });`
 all work fine and the data displayed on the screen. But surely it's not a sorted data.

Comment: What type of data is distance field? int or Integer?

Comment: You could try to return `Float.compare(lhs.getDistance(), rhs.getDistance())` in the compare method...

Comment: It is for int. Use general method. `if()`` then`

Comment: doesn't work sir.
Well i guess the error is on my `Arrays.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {`
because i want to sort the resultList not the itemList. But when i replace itemList with resultList, it's getting error. Can you check is my declaration there was right?

Comment: And also, as your itemList is aa array of Items, why don't you check sort like this `Log.d("itemList", String.valueOf(itemList[i].getDistance()));` ?

Comment: You cannot use Arrays.sort(...) with an ArrayList. It only accepts arrays as parameter... So either you make resultList an Item[] array, sort it with Arrays.sort(...) and then copy it in an ArrayList to setAdapter, either you use a clasic method of sorting an Arraylist

Comment: ooou, so what method you recommend me to use with arrayList sir?

Comment: i displaying the arrayList to the user with ListView, is there any recommendation from you sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
        return lhs.getDistance().compareTo(rhs.getDistance());//mungkin valuenya null
    }
});
```

Comment: Also pay attention that getDistance method must return a Float.